# Factory pattern to build multiple models

Tags: c#, factory-method

I have used the factory pattern for one of my projects.
I want to know if this is a good design or if my code can be improved to make it as fast as possible.

I am not an expert in C#.
This is what I came up with after 2 days of research, with lots of rewrites.
What I want to ask is:
Is this the right approach?
Can I improve it to be faster and safer?

**Source Problem:**
There is incoming data which includes JSON data. Data structure is like:

```
char.base {"level": 20, "name": "somename"}
```

What I call first `char.base` part is the module.
There are 12 modules like this and each of them have different properties.

```
// ./Models/Model.cs
namespace Example.Models
{
    public abstract class Model
    {
    }
}
```

Those 12 models have their own classes which uses this `Model` class as their base. Example Model:

```
// ./Models/Base.cs
namespace Example.Models
{
    public class Base : Model
    {
        public int Level { get; internal set; }
        public string? Name { get; internal set; }
    }
}
```

Factory class:

```
namespace Example
{
    internal abstract class Factory
    {
        public Type Type { get => typeof(Factory); }

        internal abstract void Deserialize(string json);
    }

    internal class Factory<T> : Factory where T : Model
    {
        public new Type Type { get => typeof(T); }
        private JsonSerializerOptions _options = new() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
        private Root _root { get; set; }

        internal Factory(Root root)
        {
            _root = root;
        }

        internal override void Deserialize(string json)
        {
            T? obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json, _options);

            if (obj == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"{typeof(T)} cannot be deserialized with the given data: {json}");

            _root.AddOrUpdate(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally Root class that gets the incoming data and sends to the right factory:

```
namespace Example
{
    public class Root
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, Factory> ModelFactory;
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Model> Models = new();

        public Root()
        {
            ModelFactory = new()
            {
                { "char.base", new Factory<Base>(this) },
                // 11 more like this
            };
        }

        public void Parse(string text)
        {
            int i = text.IndexOf(' ');
            if (i < 0)
                return;

            // text: char.base {...}
            // text: [module] [JSON]
            string module = text[..i].ToLower();
            string json = text[(i + 1)..];

            if (!ModelFactory.ContainsKey(module))
                return;

            ModelFactory[module].Deserialize(json);

        }

        public T? Get<T>() where T : Model, new()
        {
            return (T)Models.GetOrAdd(typeof(T), _ => new T());
        }

        internal void AddOrUpdate<T>(T value) where T : Model
        {
            Models.AddOrUpdate(typeof(T), value, (key, oldValue) => value);
        }
    }
}
```

The codes that needs these models will get it like this:

```
var base = root.Get<Base>();
```

**Edit**

Here is some sample incoming data:

```
char.base { "name": "Valour", "class": "Warrior", "subclass": "Soldier", "race": "Elf", "clan": "wolf", "pretitle": "Testing ", "perlevel": 1000, "tier": 1, "remorts": 7 }
```

```
char.vitals { "hp": 100000, "mana": 90000, "moves": 41599 }
```

```
comm.tick { }
```

There is nothing going on with the Model classes. Just some getter properties according to these JSON data.

Comment: Maybe I abstract generic model class would be more suitable?

Comment: Or maybe simple ```switch``` statement? But I will have to rewrite same code for every model with against with DRY coding?

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview! Could you please share with us two or three sample inputs and related `Model` derived classes? It would give us more context why did you choose Factory method.

Comment: `There are 12 modules like this and each of them have different properties.` can you give us two different samples of the `Json` data

Comment: I added some sample data @PeterCsala

Comment: I made an edit to the question @iSR5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have over-engineered the problem. You don't need neither the `Factory` nor the `Factory<T>` classes.

```
public class Root
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Type> ModelMapping;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Model> Models = new();
    private readonly JsonSerializerOptions Options = new() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };

    public Root()
    {
        ModelMapping = new()
        {
            { "char.base", typeof(Base) },
            // 11 more like this
        };
    }

    public void Parse(string text)
    {
        int separatorIdx = text.IndexOf(' ');
        if (separatorIdx < 0) return;
        string module = text[..separatorIdx].ToLower();

        if (!ModelMapping.ContainsKey(module)) return;

        string json = text[(separatorIdx + 1)..];

        var parsed = Deserialize(json, ModelMapping[module]);
        Models.AddOrUpdate(ModelMapping[module], parsed, (key, oldValue) => parsed);
    }

    private Model Deserialize(string json, Type parseTo)
        => JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json, parseTo, Options) as Model
            ?? throw new ArgumentNullException($"{parseTo} cannot be deserialized with the given data: {json}");

    public T? Get<T>() where T : Model, new()
        => (T)Models.GetOrAdd(typeof(T), _ => new T());
}
```

- I've replaced your `ModelFactory` to `ModelMapping` (maps `string` to `Type`)
- I've moved the `Deserialize` method from the `Factory` to here

  - I've also changed the return type from `void` to `Model`
  - Now the `Parse` can call the `AddOrUpdate` method
- I've made the `Deserialize` work on `Type` rather than expecting a `T` type parameter

---

I've used to following code for testing:

```
var @base = new Base { Name = "test", Level = 20 };
var source = @"char.base " + JsonSerializer.Serialize(@base);
var root = new Root();
root.Parse(source);
var newBase = root.Get<Base>();
Console.WriteLine(newBase.Level == @base.Level);
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems I really over-engineered the problem. I always forget the easy method is the best method most of the time!

Comment: @Valour In addition of @Peter-Csala answer, It would be more feasible if you just make use of `JsonSerializerOptions` and add custom `JsonConverter` to work with these incoming `Json`. find out more about it here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Comment: Can I use records instead of class in models with this code?

Comment: @Valour yes you can.